# Automatic folder syncing on Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-home-server

Is there a way for Windows Home Server to keep one of its share folders sync'd with a folder on one of the computers on the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en) - there is another question regarding this here

Comment: Just learned how to setup SyncToy to run on as scheduled task. Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: [Windows Live Sync as a Service on Windows Home Server](http://mswhs.freeforums.org/windows-live-sync-as-a-service-on-whs-t623.html), [Windows Live Sync](http://sync.live.com/) should run fine, and would do what you want.

You'll need a Live account, and then you just set up a private folder and share it on the two machines, and they'll be kept in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Offline Files?

Answer (score 0):

I use Unison. It's a pain to configure on Windows, but it's much much faster than any other syncing tool